# BlockHound allowBlocking not working with junit5

Tags: spring-webflux, junit5, blockhound

I am using blockhound to detect blocking calls, I would like to allow my custom methods but its not working and still throwing error.

i am using junit5 with blockhound-junit-platform

```
@BeforeAll
        static void configureBlockHound(){
                System.out.println("called");
                BlockHound.builder().allowBlockingCallsInside(JWTHelper.class.getName(), "toToken").install();
        }
```

When i run the test i can see `called`  printed on console but still throwing exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run blockhound in "log-only" mode first to understand the root cause.

```
BlockHound.install(builder -> builder
        .blockingMethodCallback(method -> 
                log.error("[{}] Blocking call: {}", Thread.currentThread(), method))
);
```